# Questions regarding profanities ("русский мат") - allowed or not?

Tags: discussion

One distinctive feature of modern Russian language is that profanities are not used simply to emphasize normal language, but in most use cases substitute core words in sentences and bring a meaning of their own. I've seen many exchange students struggling to understand casual Russian dialogs containing *мат*, though their grasp of spoken language was satisfactory or even good.

The question here - should we allow the questions regarding origins, meaning and proper use of Russian profanities? If there are [500-pages dictionaries](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/92773/) dedicated simply to *мат*, doesn't it mean that we should dedicate time to questions regarding it?

Answer (score 13):

Sure thing we should! Isn't it the most remarkable part of the Russian language?

Comment: It's hopefully not, but I agree to allow it.

Comment: Also I wouldn't say that this is a part of Russian language only. As far as I know, other Slavic languages have the same words.

Comment: Malcolm, did anybody but you said anything about it being a solely Russian thing?

Answer (score 10):

They should be allowed with certain provisions:

- Question titles should not contain profanity
- Questions should be tagged accordingly, so that they may be filtered out
- They should satisfy all other quality requirements and not contain vulgarity for the sake of vulgarity.

Comment: Why no profanity in the title? I'd prefer "What's the origin of [word]" over "What's the origin of this swear word?" as an informative title.

Comment: @ТимН because not everybody wants to see profanity?

Comment: kotkezot, at the same time not everybody is embarrassed by the profanity being an essential part of their mother language.

Comment: @bonomo that doesn't mean we should offend people.

Comment: kotekzot, there must be something said in FAQ or the disclaimer section about that, which is what most people do not to offend the others

Comment: oh, i am sorry i though i did my best, now it's your turn, itn't it?

Comment: kotekzok, thank you for being so kind and letting me know about your limitations, next time i will put some extra effort to make sure people with like you won't be left aside.

Comment: kotekzok, I feel so tired tonight, can I do it tomorrow, I promise I will

Comment: Tags about that would probably be meta tags.

Comment: @Alenanno are you suggesting we create a separate method of filtering out those questions then, or that we shouldn't provide that option at all?

Comment: I don't know how other sites handled it... Perhaps we could ask other language sites?

Comment: Just create a suitable tag like "profanity" or "mat". Although Cyrillic tags don't work, the Latin capital form MAT would work.

Comment: I agree with @TимН... Profanity should be allowed in titles.

Comment: If we are tagging, then that tag should be ignored for anonymous users and by default. Should we let Google see the questions?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS I think hiding them by default is a little too much. Perhaps a popup asking whether you'd like questions re: profanity to be hidden?

Comment: And a cookie to keep that override?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS yes.

Comment: This should be standard for all language sites on SE.

Answer (score 5):

Since the community is torn between the 2 existing options (all-out profanity or heavily regulated profanity), I'm posting this revised suggestion.

They should be allowed with certain provisions:

- Questions should be tagged accordingly, so that they may be filtered out
- They should satisfy all other quality requirements and not contain vulgarity for the sake of vulgarity.